# Prime Infrastructure IOS-XE device type recognition

Tags: snmp, stacking, ios-xe, prime

Catalyst switches usually form a stack on boot up, even if they are not stacked. They just form a stack with themselves. So Prime Infrastructure reads out the model of the switch, that says it is a stack. This leads to the fact, that the device model will be displayed as **Cisco Catalyst 29xx Stack-able Ethernet Switch** in Prime.

[image]

There was a fix in IOS that told the switch to not report the stack, but the model via SNMP instead.

```
no snmp-server sysobjectid type stack-oid
```

This lead to a clean Prime Infrastructure database.

[image]

Now this command is not working on IOS-XE and this leads to the same bad database issue we have had in the past:

[image]

Does anybody know a fix for this in IOS-XE?

Comment: "_Catalyst switches usually form a stack on boot up, even if they are not stacked._" What does that mean? I can install a bunch of stackable switches without actually creating a stack, and the switches do not form a stack, even if they are directly connected to each other.

Comment: What XE version?

Comment: @RonTrunk: I am guessing it affects all XE versions, but i tested 16.6.4 & 16.09.06

Comment: @RonMaupin: While booting up you can see this line in the log: `%STACKMGR-4-SWITCH_ADDED: Switch 1 has been ADDED to the stack` and if you issue `show switch` you can see that there is a stack with one member only.

Comment: Right, a single stack switch is a stack with one member, but the switches do not form stacks with other stack switches, they are, themselves, stacks, and I would want that reported as such because if you add more switches to the stack, you would only see the stack as a single switch.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Well thats nice, but sometimes I would like to deploy a certain configuration to just the 2960X switches that have PoE, or 10Gig uplink ports and so on... It helps alot if I can differentiate the models from within prime for a config deployment. Threre is a fix for IOS, so im looking for a similar fix for IOS-XE.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm command:

```
(no) snmp-server sysobjectid type stack-oid
```

is not implemented in IOS-XE 16.03.x / 16.06.x / 16.12.x - I assume all IOS-XE 16.x versions are affected.
There is a Bug CSCvd39747 describing the issue with IOS-XE 16.3.2 - sadly no fixed versions are mentioned at all :o(

However the command was implemented and worked in legacy IOS-XE 3.x versions